# qwt- how to customize the scale numbers shown in a QwtKnob

Tags: qt, qwt

As said in the question I'm trying to change the numbers shown in the scale part of a *QwtKnob*.
This is exactly the situation:

I have this knob with the values between 1 to 100. Now when I set its range to between 1 and 100 with the step of 1 its scale shows the numbers 20, 40,60,80,100 (**NOT 1**) and when I set the range to between 0 and 100 it also shows 0. Now what can I do to make it show the numbers like 1,10,20,30, etc ?

I've read about reimplementing *QwtScaleDraw* but could find out what exactly to do

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach:

```
// Rescale the knob appearance
QList<double> l_list[QwtScaleDiv::NTickTypes];
l_list[QwtScaleDiv::MajorTick].append(1);
 for (int i=2;i<=100;i++)
{
    if (i%20==0)
        l_list[QwtScaleDiv::MajorTick].append(i);
}
QwtScaleDiv l_sc(1,100,l_list);
your_knob_->setScale(l_sc);
```